# MathJax with Node partials

Tags: node.js, express, latex, ejs, mathjax

I'm using Node and Express with MathJax to make a comment system with TeX. The problem is, the TeX is only rendered when the page first loads, or when I refresh the page, but does not load when rendering a partial. Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the MathJax documentation on [dynamic pages](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html), which will suggest that you use

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
```

after adding math to the page.

Also, you could check out the [MathJax-node](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node) project, which implements APIs for interacting with MathJax through node.js programs.